# Can I build 3D or 2D interactive games using React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React runs a JS V8 engine to build the UI in Native. It can obviously hook into the OpenGL native library but can we actually build performant Games using React Native?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it can be done and the performance looks pretty neat.

Here is a video which demonstrate the same for iOS: [A Quick React Native Demo with OpenGL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPFf53fdUmQ)

OpenGL for Android can also be hooked up in a similar way.

Comment: So you use react native for the controls and all the openGL is done in Objective-c? So this is entirely useless for multi-platform development and therefor React?
Why does this have 13 upvotes?

Comment: seconded - this is just showing how to create a native component on top of the native OpenGL ES API.

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on what type of game you're going to build. I rebuilt my  [nonogram puzzle game](https://www.falcross.com/) from Obj-C to React Native, and after putting effort into optimization (eliminating redundant renders, using fewer components, and using the Animated API wherever possible), the performance in RN was just a good as Obj-C.

However, this is a 2D puzzle game that doesn't use any sort of fancy  rendering--it is just a grid with numbers and a few simple animations. I will also note that I did have to write the grid itself in native code, as it would generate up to 625 RN Views (for a 25x25) puzzle and that just killed performance when it rendered.

In conclusion, RN it without any external libraries is fine for simpler 2D games like puzzles, but I'd hesitate to use it for anything like a platformer, action or 3D game--it's just not made for that.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at Expo and its [GLView](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v15.0.0/sdk/gl-view.html) component, which interfaces with the native OpenGL interface but exposes it using a WebGL type API.

You can even use Three.js with that, using the [expo-three](https://github.com/expo/expo-three) library (which is rough around the edges, but sufficiently simple that you could tweak it around for your needs). But really since you have access to the WebGL gl object, you could use any js lib which uses WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

2D - Yes

We can use [react-native-game-engine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-game-engine) for that, It's an Awesome library for simple React Native 2D Games

Checkout my simple Interactive **2D game using React Native**

[Video Sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qi4BsLp4ZxI)

[Get it from Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.colorsplash)

[image] ----------- [image]